# Java - Recursion to replace letter in string

Tags: java, string

I am full aware that strings are immutable and can't be changed and can be "editabile" - ohhh the controversy! So I am trying to get it so that **without** the replace() method for strings in java, to implement where a specific char in a string gets switched out with another char. I want to do this as simply as possibly without needing to import any util or use arrays. thus far, I've gotten it to change the character, but it's not returning correctly, or, that is... the string ends.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String words = "hello world, i am a java program, how are you today?";
    char from = 'a';
    char to = '/';

    replace(s, from, to);
}
public static String replace(String s, char from, char to){
    if (s.length() < 1)
        return s;
    if (s.charAt(0) == from) {
        s = to + s.substring(1);
    }
    System.out.println(s);
return s.charAt(0) + replace(s.substring(1, s.length()), from, to);
}
```

Comment: Use a StringBuilder as that's what it's for. Nothing fancy about doing this, and in fact it's whole lot cleaner and simpler than recursion.

Comment: Do you want to modify the existing string or create a new string from the existing one ?

Comment: In your return statement you end up creating a new instance of the String which is not as per the requirement mentioned by you.

Answer (score 10):

How does this strike you? Fun with tail recursion.

```
public class Demo {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String words = "hello world, i am a java program, how are you today?";
    char from = 'a';
    char to = '/';

    System.out.println(replace(words, from, to));
  }

  public static String replace(String s, char from, char to){
    if (s.length() < 1) {
      return s;
    }
    else {
      char first = from == s.charAt(0) ? to : s.charAt(0);
      return first + replace(s.substring(1), from, to);
    }
  }

}
```

Output:

```
C:\>java Demo
hello world, i /m / j/v/ progr/m, how /re you tod/y?
```

Comment: This is the best approach.

Answer (score 4):

```
 Try this code work for u enjoy it
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    String words = "hello world, i am a java program, how are you today?";
    char from = 'a';
    char to = '/';

    //String ss = words.replace(from, to);
    System.out.println(words);
    String ss = replace(words, from, to);// recieveing String from replace()
    System.out.println("New Replace String is =>  "+ss );
    }

public static String replace(String s, char from, char to){
    if (s.length() < 1)
        return s;
         for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
        if (s.charAt(i) == from) {
            s = s.substring(0, i)+to + s.substring(++i);
            System.out.println(s);
            return replace(s, from, to);//calling replace()
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

**Output is ** New Replace String is =>  hello world, i /m / j/v/ progr/m, how /re you tod/y?

Answer (score 2):

You can work this by using the "charAt" method for String an putting appropriate characters into a StringBuffer and then running "toString" on the StringBuffer

```
public class Replacement {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String words = "hello world, i am a java program, how are you today?";
    char from = 'a';
    char to = '/';

    String changed = replace(words, from, to);
    System.out.println(words);
    System.out.println(changed);
}

public static String replace(String s, char from, char to) {
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(s.length());

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) == from) {
            result.append(to);
        } else {
            result.append(s.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    return result.toString();

}
```

}

Comment: +1 for using StringBuilder. I personally like the non-recursive version since it's cleaner and easier to understand.

Comment: @tonga - it's using StringBuffer which is useful in multithread execution

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Java predefined class StringBuilder. It is more effective than concatenating and manipulating Strings directly. StringBuilder also has a replace() method to cater your problem. See documentation [StringBuilder#replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#replace%28int,%20int,%20java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I've a very simple answer

```
public class Replacer {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
          String words = "hello world, i am a java program, how are you today?";
    char from = 'a';
    char to = '/';

    //String ss = words.replace(from, to);
    System.out.println(words);
    String ss = replace(words, from, to);// recieveing String from replace()
    System.out.println("New Replace String is =>  "+ss );
    }

    
    public static String replace(String s, char from, char to)
    {
        int pos = s.indexOf(from);
        
        // If not found, return the string as such
        if (pos < 0)
        {
            return s;
        }
        
        // Split the string by 'from' and join with 'to'
        return s.substring(0, pos) + to + replace(s.substring(pos+1), from, to);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, Hovercraft Full of Eels is correct. StringBuilder is your friend. It is mutable, you can just feed your String into StringBuilder and then do your swapping and call toString() at the end and your done.

Answer (score -1):

```
 public String changeXY(String str)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)) return str;           
        if(str[0] == 'x')
        {
            return 'y' +  changeXY(str.Substring(1,str.Length - 1));
        }
        else
        {
            return str[0] +  changeXY(str.Substring(1, str.Length - 1));
        }
    }
```

Comment: This needs to import guava library, which should be avoided as per the question. Also, try to compile the code before posting